# How to run async tasks indefinitely using timer with different dealys

Tags: c#, asynchronous, timer, task, .net-4.6

I am working on a console application. I organized common operations in tasks. Each task (say task1, task2, task3) should run indefinitely based on its own delay (eg. task1 every 5 minutes, task2 every hour, and task3 once a day). When user closes the app it should wait till all running tasks are finished and all pending should be cancelled.
The problem is that I don't know how to do that in a proper way. I tried something like the below code but the main process exists as soon as it reaches t1.Start() line. It is expected behaviour but I have completely no idea how to proceed.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string path = @"config.json";
        Config config = ConfigParser.Parse(path);

        TimerTask t1 = new TimerTask(async () => await Task1(config), 300000);
        t1.Start();
    }
}

private static async Task Task1(Config config)
{
    // read from a database
    // call external service
    // write to the database
}    

public class TimerTask
{
    private readonly Timer taskTimer;

    public TimerTask(Action action, int interval = 10000)
    {
        taskTimer = new Timer { AutoReset = true, Interval = interval };
        taskTimer.Elapsed += (_, __) => action();
    }

    public void Start() { taskTimer.Start(); }

    public void Stop() { taskTimer.Stop(); }
}
```

Comment: I thik you just need a `Console.ReadKey` so your program doesn't exit until the user presses a key or something like that

Comment: So wait after you call the Start method? You can ask and wait for a user input, that way it won't exit after `t1.Start`. The simplest way to do it is just use `Console.Read()`

Comment: It is not clear how you expect your task to complete, but the marked duplicate explains how you can wait for that to happen. As far as the timers themselves go, I would not use the `Timer` class. Since you are using `Task` objects anyway, you should write your intermittent tasks as `async` methods, using `Task.Delay()`, and you can `WaitAll()` the tasks, once you have done whatever it is you need to do to signal to them to stop running.

Comment: @Selman Genç I am aware of this but then the app exits as soon as any key is pressed. And any running task is interrupted which is not what I am looking for. Running tasks should be finished before main process can exit.